# How do I know the build number for the current project in Jenkins?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, environment-variables, jenkins

I am aware of the `BUILD_NUMBER` environment variable; however, unless I'm mistaken, this is a **global** variable which appears to be shared among all projects. This is a problem since, if I have two agents running jobs, one script may try to use the current project's build number after another script has updated it for a different project.

Here is an example scenario:

- Job **J<sub>1</sub>** starts, executing some script **S**. `BUILD_NUMBER` is currently, let's say, 500.
- Someone manually starts job **J<sub>2</sub>**, which now sets `BUILD_NUMBER` to something completely different, say, 750.
- Script **S**, which is still running, now reaches the point where it actually uses `BUILD_NUMBER`, now set to 750 (an impossible value for job **J<sub>1</sub>**, which is only up to 500).

Am I correct in this understanding? If so, how do I address this problem?

Comment: I'm fairly certain your understanding is incorrect. Why don't you just set up two jobs that say, sleeps for a while and then prints out the BUILD_NUMBER, just to see for yourself?

Comment: @Jack Leow: But that's exactly what I've done! It's very strange. I guess I'll have to seek a different explanation.

Answer (score 10):

BUILD_NUMBER is not global to the system.  It's local to each job.  In your example, J1 and J2 will have different BUILD_NUMBER (J1=500, J2-750) values and they will remain constant - within the job - for the duration of the job.

Comment: I hope you're right; however, if that's the case, I'm having great difficulty understanding how I could see what I'm seeing (i.e., a script run within J1 produced output with `BUILD_NUMBER` 671, despite the fact that J1's build numbers only went up to 305... meanwhile, the latest build number for *J2* is 671). I guess there must be some other explanation; any idea what it could be?

Comment: I'm certain - at least for an up-to-date Jenkins.  We use BUILD_NUMBER in several of our jobs and it's always properly set.  One way to verify - insert a "Execute Windows batch command" and have the command be just "set".  This will dump the variables out to the console and you can see what the values are.  Note that there plugins that may execute their code - and parameter resolution - differently or in a context where BUILD_NUMBER does not evaluate properly.

Comment: But do your jobs ever run in parallel, or do they run one after the other?

Comment: I suspect it may be your last point--about plugins executing code in a different context--that ultimately explains what I'm seeing. Investigation under way!

Comment: I run jobs in parallel and in series.  In both cases, BUILD_NUMBER worked as expected.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the **latest** (completed or currently executing) build number with:
`http://[JENKINS_URL]/job/[JOB_NAME]/lastBuild/buildNumber`
or from within the job itself, you can use environment variable:
`${BUILD_NUMBER}`

You can use all other permalinks too, like:
`/lastStableBuild/`
`/lastSuccessfulBuild/`
`/lastFailedBuild/`
and so on.

Unless you are customizing your build number with a plugin such as **[Next Build Number](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Next+Build+Number+Plugin)**, your **next** build number will always be an **increment to the latest** build number.

The build numbers are **per job**. They are not global environment variables.
Every time any job is executed, it **copies/inherits** existing environment variables into a **new session**. Jenkins/Hudson then adds all job parameters and extra variables (including `${BUILD_NUMBER}`) to that new session. They are available as environment variables only for the duration of that session (i.e. for the duration of the job run). Once the job completes, this **session is destroyed** (along with all the extra variables that were generated for the session).

You **cannot** access the *environment* variables of one job-run/session from another job-run/session. You *can* however access the `/lastBuild/buildNumber` of another job through the URL method I provided. You can also access `/lastBuild/buildTimestamp` the same way.

To access *job parameters* of another job, you can use:
`http://[JENKINS_URL]/job/[JOB_NAME]/lastBuild/api/json`
or
`http://[JENKINS_URL]/job/[JOB_NAME]/lastBuild/api/xml`
but you would need to parse the output for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Get Next Build Number plugin.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Next+Build+Number+Plugin